# MYSql DR on Azure

Tags: mysql, azure, disaster-recovery

We are planning to host a Disaster recovery of our on-premises mysql to Azure. I know it could be done using master-slave approach if both servers are on-premises.

Any expert could explain the high level steps of achieving it when the master server will be on-premises while other server remains on azure ?

Comment: http://sabbour.me/highly-available-and-scalable-master-master-mysql-on-azure-virtual-machines/#comment-1767144329